# External SMTP setup on Azure

Tags: php, html, email, azure, smtp

I have a website on Azure Web Apps and want to enable SMTP settings to be able to receive emails through my websites contact form. One of the solutions that I found on this forum were to use an external SMTP. I went over to my web root and modified the php.ini file, changing the default SMTP settings to the external SMTP I want to use. I changed the SMTP server name and the port number. 
However, that does not suffice. I need to provide credentials for SMTP relay, and I don't understand how SMTP authentication comes into play here. I am currently using the mail function in my HTML form with PHP handling.

If someone could please guide me on the process, I'd be highly grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, on Azure, you don't need to use External SMTP server to send emails in your app. You can easily use SendGrid to satisfy this.

Here is a detailed guide on how to use the SendGrid email service from PHP: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-php-how-to-send-email/.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing just that. Thank you.